# BootStrap Modal data attributes not refreshing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

On Click of the Edit Button  , i am showing  a Modal with the  name present under corresponding data attribute  **data-catname**

I am changing the name inside the Modal and updating the text and also the corresponding  data attribute **data-catname**

But When i reopen the Modal , its showing me the prevoius name

This is my code

```
function addCatSbmt()
{
        var category_name_modal = $("#catnameedit").val();
        var category_id_modal = $("#catidhiddenedit").val();
        var trid = category_id_modal;
        var texttoreplace = category_name_modal;
        $("#span" + trid).text(texttoreplace);
        $('#' + trid).find(".editcatclick").attr('data-catname', texttoreplace);
          $('.closetagdialog').trigger('click');
}
```

**How to Reproduce :**

1.Click on Edit button (TCS) , it will open a POP UP , with the name TCS , change the name to something else .

2.Click again the same Edit button , it is showing TCS only

https://jsfiddle.net/BVV5T/313/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I the issue is with `.data()` function which been used in modal show function.

Replace `.data` with `.attr` and you will achieve your desired result.

```
$('#editCategoryname').on('show.bs.modal', function(e)
{
        var cat_name = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-catname');
        var cat_id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-categorid');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="catnameedit"]').val(cat_name);
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="catidhiddenedit"]').val(cat_id);
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BVV5T/314/)

-Help :)

Comment: Glad to help :) Please don't forget to accept the answer as this mite help others too :)

Comment: I think you can do it by data attribute by doing some changes in add method

Answer (score 1):

You can access using data but you need to update your data attribute in similar manner

```
data('catname',texttoreplace)
```

But to update you need to provide id to you a tag which contain your data attribute

like

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCategoryname" data-categorid="1" id="cat_1" data-catname="TCS" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary editcatclick"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
```

So this is the fiddle which one following you approach

[fiddlle](https://jsfiddle.net/BVV5T/321/)

Please check this url to study about data attribute

[jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)